# remove white space using itextpdf

Tags: java, itext, itextpdf

I am converting html data into pdf,but I got white space where  some large data will insert,  I'd like to trim off the whitespace for following data

note: header is coming from jasper report

```
'Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 40, 72, getMargins(1),20);`

document.setMarginMirroringTopBottom(true);`

String path = dao.gettomcatserverPath1() + "webapps/wordimages/disch" +patid+ ".pdf";`        

PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(path));
`String html = "";
List list1 = dao.executeQuery("select wordole from ip.dischargetemplate where patid='"+patid+"'");

html = ((Map)list1.get(0)).get("WORDOLE").toString();

InputStream _ishtml = new ByteArrayInputStream(html.getBytes());

HeaderFooter event = new HeaderFooter();`
writer.setPageEvent(event);`

writer.setBoxSize("art", new Rectangle(36, 54, 559, 788));`

document.open();`
Font font = FontFactory.getFont("Times-Roman");

XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, _ishtml);`

document.close();`
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to trim off the whitespace include the "space"?
Or just trim off the whitespace after the html sentences?

Comment: Just I want to trim off white space

Comment: It would help if you would explain which white space you are talking about. All content in a PDF is added at absolute positions. It seems that you want text to "reflow", but that requirement may very well be impossible. Of course: you may be talking about removing white space from an HTML *before* a PDF is created. If that is the case, I don't understand the problem.